# Getting a " return type defaults to 'int' " warning when I declare Shortf function before int main(). Why?

Tags: c, function, types, return, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
int w=7,v=0;
shortf(short a, short *b)
{
    a++;(*b)++;w++;v++;
    printf("13: %d %d %d",a,v,w); return a;
}
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of my code. It was given to me by a teacher in my University, but when I write it I get 10+ warnings and errors, this is one of them.
I get a " return type defaults to 'int' " warning for Line 4. Why?
Note: I am only allowed to use C.

Comment: You don't seem to have declared a return type for your function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not declare a return type for the function `shortf`. And so the compiler warned you that the default type of `int` will be used.

You should always declare a return value type. My guess is that the code has just been transcribed incorrectly. I think it should be:

```
short f(short a, short *b)
```

Comment: Clear enough, but how is the code supposed to look like? How do I declare a return value type? I am sorry for my lack of experience, I've been coding with GUI for years and transition isn't as fast as I thought it would. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: That will be in your text book. See my latest update. The return value type of f is short.

Comment: Right! I've missed a space between them, because it goes like "Type Name()", so I've merged short and f creating an... abomination? Okay, great, I have no idea where my mind was to think this would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thought I would waltz in here a little: I thought `int` would automatic be the return value when one is not specified without warnings whatsoever? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheillig A warning is just that. The compilation continues, but the compiler chooses to notify you of something that it deems suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to declare the return type of your function `shortf`. In C89, if return type of a function is omitted, the function is presumed to return a value of `int` type (by default). It should be

```
short shortf(short a, short *b) {...}
```

In C99 and latter, it is illegal to omit the return type of a function.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! I was forced to google C89 though, I guess it's the version of the language. I learned something new ^^

Comment: C89, C99, C11 all are the C standard.